# Standard Deployment EJB app

Tags: java, servlets, deployment, jboss, ejb

Is there a standardized format to deploy ejb apps on Application Servers ?

I created a jar file with only the .class files of my app and a defaulf manifest and copied it to the deployments directory of JBoss v7.1 and it deployed just fine.
I've read that it is always needed also a deployment descriptor, but I did not use it in my deployment.

I mean WAR files, used to deploy jee web apps have,I think, a standard format and structure, does exsist a similar standard also to deploy EJB apps ?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you pack your application to war file? You can deploy war file to tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a standard format, which is defined in the Java EE specification. If you're planning on deploying EJBs within your application, you will need to generate an EAR file which will contain the various modules within your application.

See [Packaging Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html) under The Java EE 6 Tutorial for more information.